# SQL Server 2008 data type for day of week

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enumerated types in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373421/enumerated-types-in-sql-server-2008)

I'm using SQL Server 2008, I need a column to be day of week, is there a way to make the column be an enumeration, so the wrong data can't be entered?

Comment: Answer will be the same as the duplicate post already given... just setup a code table with a foreign key constraint.

Comment: not a duplicate - [that Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373421/enumerated-types-in-sql-server-2008) is about compile-time enforcement. Though answers ignore that :)